# How can I automatically turn a column value in Google Sheets into a hyperlink based on the value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jira

I have a sheet where one column contains an ID to a Jira ticket.

I would like to automatically convert this to a link to the ticket, based on the value I enter.

E.g. I'll enter SD-1234 into the column, and I would like it to then make it into a clickable link to https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1234/, but not show the URL int he cell, but the original value I entered (SD-1234).

The column is always E if that helps. Can someone give me a head start with how to script this in Script Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, when the cell "E1" has `SD-1234`, `=HYPERLINK("https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/"&E1, E1)` is used, the value is `SD-1234` with the hyperlink of `https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1234`. But in this case, the result cannot be directly shown in the cell "E1". When you want to directly convert `SD-1234` in the cell "E1" to `SD-1234` with the hyperlink of `https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1234`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script and run the function at the script editor. Before you use this, please set the sheet name.

This sample script converts from `SD-1234` in the column "E" to `=HYPERLINK("https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1234", "SD-1234")`.

```js
function sample1() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("E1:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [`=HYPERLINK("${baseUrl}${e}", "${e}")`]);
  range.setFormulas(values);
}
```

This sample script converts from `SD-1234` in the column "E" to `SD-1234` with the hyperlink of `https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/SD-1234`. In this case, the formula is not used.

```js
function sample2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("E1:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(baseUrl + e).build()]);
  range.setRichTextValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- If your spreadsheet has the 1st header row, please modify `"E1:E" + sheet.getLastRow()` to `"E2:E" + sheet.getLastRow()`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValues(RichTextValue))

### Added 1:

From your following comments,

> Do I have to set the sheet name? I have several sheets that I always want this function to be applied to (I have currently over 20 sheets in the file).
>
> Also, I've entered this into Script Editor to test, and what do I do from here? There's no save that I can see... and it's not running on my sheet. How can I apply this to my sheet to automatically run whenever a value is entered in the cell?

When the above situations are reflected in the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it. And please edit the column "E" of the sheet. By this, the cell has the hyperlink with the inputted text.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to run the script.
  const column = 5; // Column E. From your question, this script run for the column "E".

  const {range} = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.columnStart != column) return;
  const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(baseUrl + e).build()]);
  range.setRichTextValues(values);
}
```

If you want to run the script for all sheets, you can use the following script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const column = 5; // Column E. From your question, this script run for the column "E".

  const {range} = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  if (range.columnStart != column) return;
  const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(baseUrl + e).build()]);
  range.setRichTextValues(values);
}
```

### Added 2:

If you want to run the script to the column "E" of all sheets by one script running, you can also use the following script.

#### Sample script:

This sample script runs for the specific sheets.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set sheet names you want to run the script.

  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) return;
    const range = sheet.getRange("E1:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(baseUrl + e).build()]);
    range.setRichTextValues(values);
  });
}
```

This sample script runs for all sheets.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const baseUrl = "https://demo.atlassian.net/browse/";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    const range = sheet.getRange("E1:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const values = range.getValues().map(([e]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(baseUrl + e).build()]);
    range.setRichTextValues(values);
  });
}
```

Comment: Do I have to set the sheet name? I have several sheets that I always want this function to be applied to (I have currently over 20 sheets in the file).

Comment: @Lee Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand such situations in your comments. I deeply apologize for this. When the situations in your comments are reflected in the script, the sample script is like above. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize again.

Comment: @Lee I'm worried whether I could correctly understand your question. So I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Please do not clutter answer posts with apologies about not understanding something - Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. Seek clarifications in the comments and then edit the post. If you don't understand the question at all, then please refrain from answering until you do.

Comment: Remember that **answers are not a conversation between you and the poster**. They are part of a generalised Q&A that is useful for many readers. Keep that general audience in mind when you answer, and if you also manage to help the question author, that is even better.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your comment. About `answers are not a conversation between you and the poster`, when I post my answer for the 1st time, I considered it. But when I updated my answer, I have forgotten it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like not to forget it for the future answer. Thank you for your always support. And, I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.